# Vertically align a too high threeparttable on landscape page while keeping fancyhdr in original place

Tags: tables, fancyhdr, landscape, threeparttable

I have a rather large `threeparttable` that was too wide to fit on a vertical page, so  I put it on a `landscape` page. But now it is a bit too high to fit between the top (left) and bottom (right) margins and runs into the lower (right?) margin. What I want is to align the table vertically, so that it runs into the top and bottom margins equally (or preferably depending on the `hmarginratio`, which I set to `1:1` for now, but will change to `2:3` for the print version).

Earlier I managed to fix this problem by setting a `newgeometry` for the landscape page, but this moved my `fancehdr`, which I like to keep in the original place so that it doesn't move when reading the printed document.

I also tried playing around with the `adjustbox` settings, but I was not able to solve my problem. Most similar questions seem to focus on tables that are less tall than text height.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,english]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,
width=16cm, %bindingoffset=-1mm, 
hmarginratio=1:1, % default=2:3
top=25mm,bottom=25mm,headheight=12mm%,showframe
]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\appto\TPTnoteSettings{\footnotesize}
\setlength{\defaultaddspace}{2pt}

\usepackage[format=default,justification=justified,labelfont=bf,font=small,skip=0pt]{caption}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[CE]{\textit{Author}}
\fancyhead[RE]{}
\fancyhead[LO]{}
\fancyhead[CO]{\textit{Title}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

This text should be on a normal page.

\begin{landscape}
    \begin{table}[h!]
        \begin{adjustbox}{valign=C,raise=2cm}
            \centering
            \begin{threeparttable}
                \caption{A long caption that spans multiple lines, so it adds considerable height tot the total table height. This makes is even more important to center the table vertically as the bottom of the tbale comes very close to the bottom of the page. This does not look good when printing the document on paper.}
                \begin{tabular}{ccccccccccccc}
                    \toprule
                    \multicolumn{ 1}{c}{\em  } & \multicolumn{12}{c}{\em Spanner head} \\
                    \cmidrule(l){2-13}
                    \multicolumn{1}{c}{ } & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Left panel} & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Right panel} \\
                    \cmidrule(lr){2-7} \cmidrule(l){8-13}
                    ${k}$ & ${Column 1}$ & ${Column2}$ & ${Column3}$ & ${Column4\tnote{a}}$ & ${Column5}$ & ${Column6\tnote{c}}$ & ${Col.1}$ & ${Col.2}$ & ${Col.3}$ & ${Col.4\tnote{a}}$ & ${Col.5}$ & ${Col.6\tnote{c}}$\\
                    \midrule
                    1 & 2.45$^{**}$ & 1.28$^{**}$ & -0.33$^{**}$ & 0.06 & 3.41 & 8.49$^{**}$ & 2.45$^{**}$ & 1.28$^{**}$ & -0.33$^{**}$ & 0.06 & 3.41 & 8.49$^{**}$\\
                    & (0.40) & (0.39) & (0.12) &  &  &  & (0.40) & (0.39) & (0.12) &  &  & \\
                    \addlinespace
                    2 & 2.29$^{**}$ & 1.55$^{**}$ & -0.40$^{**}$ & 0.13 & 2.65 & 20.42$^{**}$ & 2.20$^{**}$ & 1.79$^{**}$ & -0.47$^{**}$ & 0.12 & 3.30 & 17.51$^{**}$\\
                    & (0.44) & (0.36) & (0.11) &  &  &  & (0.36) & (0.36) & (0.12) &  &  & \\
                    \addlinespace
                    3 & 2.26$^{**}$ & 1.51$^{**}$ & -0.38$^{**}$ & 0.16 & 2.32 & 25.39$^{**}$ & 2.26$^{**}$ & 1.40$^{**}$ & -0.33$^{*}$ & 0.07 & 3.38 & 10.80$^{**}$\\
                    & (0.45) & (0.35) & (0.11) &  &  &  & (0.41) & (0.44) & (0.14) &  &  & \\
                    \addlinespace
                    4 & 2.25$^{**}$ & 1.44$^{**}$ & -0.36$^{**}$ & 0.18 & 2.09 & 29.38$^{**}$ & 2.29$^{**}$ & 1.23 & -0.27 & 0.06 & 3.41 & 8.52$^{**}$\\
                    & (0.58) & (0.33) & (0.12) &  &  &  & (0.50) & (0.68) & (0.22) &  &  & \\
                    \addlinespace
                    5 & 2.28$^{**}$ & 1.37$^{**}$ & -0.34$^{**}$ & 0.19 & 1.92 & 31.36$^{**}$ & 2.49$^{**}$ & 1.05$^{**}$ & -0.25$^{*}$ & 0.04 & 3.44 & 5.78$^{**}$\\
                    & (0.56) & (0.33) & (0.12) &  &  &  & (0.52) & (0.38) & (0.12) &  &  & \\
                    \addlinespace
                    6 & 2.34$^{**}$ & 1.24$^{**}$ & -0.30$^{**}$ & 0.19 & 1.79 & 29.83$^{**}$ & 2.71$^{**}$ & 0.57$^{*}$ & -0.12 & 0.01 & 3.50 & 1.80\\
                    & (0.58) & (0.30) & (0.11) &  &  &  & (0.53) & (0.27) & (0.10) &  &  & \\
                    \addlinespace
                    7 & 2.40$^{**}$ & 1.13$^{**}$ & -0.27$^{*}$ & 0.18 & 1.69 & 27.62$^{**}$ & 2.83$^{**}$ & 0.40 & -0.09 & 0.00 & 3.52 & 0.88\\
                    & (0.63) & (0.28) & (0.11) &  &  &  & (0.57) & (0.36) & (0.11) &  &  & \\
                    \addlinespace
                    8 & 2.48$^{**}$ & 1.03$^{**}$ & -0.25$^{*}$ & 0.16 & 1.61 & 25.02$^{**}$ & 3.07$^{**}$ & 0.27 & -0.11 & 0.00 & 3.52 & 0.44\\
                    & (0.65) & (0.26) & (0.10) &  &  &  & (0.62) & (0.72) & (0.21) &  &  & \\
                    \addlinespace
                    12 & 2.77$^{**}$ & 0.61 & -0.17 & 0.08 & 1.40 & 11.03$^{**}$ & 3.37$^{**}$ & -0.26 & 0.02 & 0.01 & 2.33 & 1.76\\
                    & (0.78) & (0.48) & (0.15) &  &  &  & (1.15) & (1.07) & (0.29) &  &  & \\
                    \addlinespace
                    16 & 2.96$^{**}$ & 0.31 & -0.09 & 0.02 & 1.25 & 3.46$^{*}$ & 3.57$^{**}$ & -0.66 & 0.13 & 0.04 & 2.24 & 5.99$^{**}$\\
                    & (1.09) & (0.36) & (0.16) &  &  &  & (0.78) & (0.41) & (0.15) &  &  & \\
                    \addlinespace
                    20 & 3.08$^{**}$ & 0.17 & -0.07 & 0.01 & 1.13 & 1.89 & 3.55$^{**}$ & -0.41 & 0.02 & 0.03 & 2.20 & 5.25$^{**}$\\
                    & (0.97) & (0.35) & (0.15) &  &  &  & (0.79) & (0.43) & (0.15) &  &  & \\
                    \bottomrule
                \end{tabular}
                \begin{tablenotes}
                    \item \textit{Notes:} 
                    \item A general note.
                    \item[a] A specific note.
                    \item[b] Another specific note.
                    \item[c] The last note.
                \end{tablenotes}
            \end{threeparttable}
        \end{adjustbox}
    \end{table}
\end{landscape}

Here the normal page orientation continues.

\end{document}
```

Comment: There is an automatic \clearpage at the beginning and end of landscape, so the [h!} totally unnecessary (not just bad practice).  In this case [p] would be better (centered).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is almost a one-line patch.  I used `\raisebox` to center the baseline and `\smash` the table, so that [p] can then center the baseline on the page.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,english]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,
width=16cm, %bindingoffset=-1mm, 
hmarginratio=1:1, % default=2:3
top=25mm,bottom=25mm,headheight=12mm%,showframe
]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\appto\TPTnoteSettings{\footnotesize}
\setlength{\defaultaddspace}{2pt}

\usepackage[format=default,justification=justified,labelfont=bf,font=small,skip=0pt]{caption}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[CE]{\textit{Author}}
\fancyhead[RE]{}
\fancyhead[LO]{}
\fancyhead[CO]{\textit{Title}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\newlength{\tempdima}% name is unimportant

\begin{document}

This text should be on a normal page.

\begin{landscape}
    \begin{table}[p]
      \centering
      \raisebox{\dimexpr 0.5\depth-0.5\height}[0pt][0pt]{\begin{threeparttable}
                \caption{A long caption that spans multiple lines, so it adds considerable height tot the total table height. This makes is even more important to center the table vertically as the bottom of the tbale comes very close to the bottom of the page. This does not look good when printing the document on paper.}
                \begin{tabular}{ccccccccccccc}
                    \toprule
                    \multicolumn{ 1}{c}{\em  } & \multicolumn{12}{c}{\em Spanner head} \\
                    \cmidrule(l){2-13}
                    \multicolumn{1}{c}{ } & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Left panel} & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Right panel} \\
                    \cmidrule(lr){2-7} \cmidrule(l){8-13}
                    ${k}$ & ${Column 1}$ & ${Column2}$ & ${Column3}$ & ${Column4\tnote{a}}$ & ${Column5}$ & ${Column6\tnote{c}}$ & ${Col.1}$ & ${Col.2}$ & ${Col.3}$ & ${Col.4\tnote{a}}$ & ${Col.5}$ & ${Col.6\tnote{c}}$\\
                    \midrule
                    1 & 2.45$^{**}$ & 1.28$^{**}$ & -0.33$^{**}$ & 0.06 & 3.41 & 8.49$^{**}$ & 2.45$^{**}$ & 1.28$^{**}$ & -0.33$^{**}$ & 0.06 & 3.41 & 8.49$^{**}$\\
                    & (0.40) & (0.39) & (0.12) &  &  &  & (0.40) & (0.39) & (0.12) &  &  & \\
                    \addlinespace
                    2 & 2.29$^{**}$ & 1.55$^{**}$ & -0.40$^{**}$ & 0.13 & 2.65 & 20.42$^{**}$ & 2.20$^{**}$ & 1.79$^{**}$ & -0.47$^{**}$ & 0.12 & 3.30 & 17.51$^{**}$\\
                    & (0.44) & (0.36) & (0.11) &  &  &  & (0.36) & (0.36) & (0.12) &  &  & \\
                    \addlinespace
                    3 & 2.26$^{**}$ & 1.51$^{**}$ & -0.38$^{**}$ & 0.16 & 2.32 & 25.39$^{**}$ & 2.26$^{**}$ & 1.40$^{**}$ & -0.33$^{*}$ & 0.07 & 3.38 & 10.80$^{**}$\\
                    & (0.45) & (0.35) & (0.11) &  &  &  & (0.41) & (0.44) & (0.14) &  &  & \\
                    \addlinespace
                    4 & 2.25$^{**}$ & 1.44$^{**}$ & -0.36$^{**}$ & 0.18 & 2.09 & 29.38$^{**}$ & 2.29$^{**}$ & 1.23 & -0.27 & 0.06 & 3.41 & 8.52$^{**}$\\
                    & (0.58) & (0.33) & (0.12) &  &  &  & (0.50) & (0.68) & (0.22) &  &  & \\
                    \addlinespace
                    5 & 2.28$^{**}$ & 1.37$^{**}$ & -0.34$^{**}$ & 0.19 & 1.92 & 31.36$^{**}$ & 2.49$^{**}$ & 1.05$^{**}$ & -0.25$^{*}$ & 0.04 & 3.44 & 5.78$^{**}$\\
                    & (0.56) & (0.33) & (0.12) &  &  &  & (0.52) & (0.38) & (0.12) &  &  & \\
                    \addlinespace
                    6 & 2.34$^{**}$ & 1.24$^{**}$ & -0.30$^{**}$ & 0.19 & 1.79 & 29.83$^{**}$ & 2.71$^{**}$ & 0.57$^{*}$ & -0.12 & 0.01 & 3.50 & 1.80\\
                    & (0.58) & (0.30) & (0.11) &  &  &  & (0.53) & (0.27) & (0.10) &  &  & \\
                    \addlinespace
                    7 & 2.40$^{**}$ & 1.13$^{**}$ & -0.27$^{*}$ & 0.18 & 1.69 & 27.62$^{**}$ & 2.83$^{**}$ & 0.40 & -0.09 & 0.00 & 3.52 & 0.88\\
                    & (0.63) & (0.28) & (0.11) &  &  &  & (0.57) & (0.36) & (0.11) &  &  & \\
                    \addlinespace
                    8 & 2.48$^{**}$ & 1.03$^{**}$ & -0.25$^{*}$ & 0.16 & 1.61 & 25.02$^{**}$ & 3.07$^{**}$ & 0.27 & -0.11 & 0.00 & 3.52 & 0.44\\
                    & (0.65) & (0.26) & (0.10) &  &  &  & (0.62) & (0.72) & (0.21) &  &  & \\
                    \addlinespace
                    12 & 2.77$^{**}$ & 0.61 & -0.17 & 0.08 & 1.40 & 11.03$^{**}$ & 3.37$^{**}$ & -0.26 & 0.02 & 0.01 & 2.33 & 1.76\\
                    & (0.78) & (0.48) & (0.15) &  &  &  & (1.15) & (1.07) & (0.29) &  &  & \\
                    \addlinespace
                    16 & 2.96$^{**}$ & 0.31 & -0.09 & 0.02 & 1.25 & 3.46$^{*}$ & 3.57$^{**}$ & -0.66 & 0.13 & 0.04 & 2.24 & 5.99$^{**}$\\
                    & (1.09) & (0.36) & (0.16) &  &  &  & (0.78) & (0.41) & (0.15) &  &  & \\
                    \addlinespace
                    20 & 3.08$^{**}$ & 0.17 & -0.07 & 0.01 & 1.13 & 1.89 & 3.55$^{**}$ & -0.41 & 0.02 & 0.03 & 2.20 & 5.25$^{**}$\\
                    & (0.97) & (0.35) & (0.15) &  &  &  & (0.79) & (0.43) & (0.15) &  &  & \\
                    \bottomrule
                \end{tabular}
                \begin{tablenotes}
                    \item \textit{Notes:} 
                    \item A general note.
                    \item[a] A specific note.
                    \item[b] Another specific note.
                    \item[c] The last note.
                \end{tablenotes}
            \end{threeparttable}}%
    \end{table}
\end{landscape}

Here the normal page orientation continues.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would remove `table` environment as well `adjusbox`. Rather I would use `small` font size and smaller array stretch, and replace `c` column type with `S` from `siunitx` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,english]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,
            width=16cm, %bindingoffset=-1mm,
            hmarginratio=1:1, % default=2:3
            vmargin=25mm,
            headheight=12mm%,showframe
            ]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
%\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}   % not used in this MWE
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{array,                % new
            booktabs}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{>{$}c<{$}}{#1}} % new
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\appto\TPTnoteSettings{\footnotesize}
\setlength{\defaultaddspace}{3pt}  % increased from 2pt
\usepackage{siunitx}               % new

\usepackage[format=default,
            %justification=justified,
            labelfont=bf,
            font=small,
            skip=0pt]{caption}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[CE]{\textit{Author}}
\fancyhead[RE]{}
\fancyhead[LO]{}
\fancyhead[CO]{\textit{Title}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

This text should be on a normal page.

\begin{landscape}
%    \begin{table}[h!]
%        \begin{adjustbox}{valign=C,raise=2cm} 
\sisetup{input-symbols = {( )},          
         table-align-text-post=false,    
        }
\renewcommand\arraystretch{0.8}  % <-----
\small                           % <-----
\begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{A long caption that spans multiple lines, so it adds considerable height tot the total table height. This makes is even more important to center the table vertically as the bottom of the tbale comes very close to the bottom of the page. This does not look good when printing the document on paper.}
    \begin{tabular}{c
                    *{3}{S[table-format=-1.2,
                           table-space-text-post={$^{**}$}]}
                    *{2}{S[table-format=1.2]}
                         S[table-format=2.2,
                           table-space-text-post={$^{**}$}]
                    *{3}{S[table-format=-1.2,
                           table-space-text-post={$^{**}$}]}
                    *{2}{S[table-format=1.2]}
                         S[table-format=2.2,
                           table-space-text-post={$^{**}$}]
                    }
        \toprule
        & \multicolumn{12}{c}{\emph{Spanner head}}  \\
        \cmidrule(l){2-13}
        & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Left panel} & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Right panel} \\
        \cmidrule(lr){2-7} \cmidrule(l){8-13}
    ${k}$   & \mc{Column 1} & \mc{Column 2} & \mc{Column 3} & \mc{Column 4\tnote{a}}
            & \mc{Column 5} & \mc{Column 6\tnote{c}}
            & \mc{Col. 1}   & \mc{Col. 2}   & \mc{Col. 3}   & \mc{Col. 4\tnote{a}} 
            & \mc{Col. 5}   & \mc{Col. 6\tnote{c}}  \\
        \midrule
        1 & 2.45\tnote{**} & 1.28\tnote{**} & -0.33\tnote{**} & 0.06 & 3.41 & 8.49\tnote{**} & 2.45\tnote{**} & 1.28\tnote{**} & -0.33\tnote{**} & 0.06 & 3.41 & 8.49\tnote{**}\\
        & (0.40) & (0.39) & (0.12) &  &  &  & (0.40) & (0.39) & (0.12) &  &  & \\
        \addlinespace
        2 & 2.29\tnote{**} & 1.55\tnote{**} & -0.40\tnote{**} & 0.13 & 2.65 & 20.42\tnote{**} & 2.20\tnote{**} & 1.79\tnote{**} & -0.47\tnote{**} & 0.12 & 3.30 & 17.51\tnote{**}\\
        & (0.44) & (0.36) & (0.11) &  &  &  & (0.36) & (0.36) & (0.12) &  &  & \\
        \addlinespace
        3 & 2.26\tnote{**} & 1.51\tnote{**} & -0.38\tnote{**} & 0.16 & 2.32 & 25.39\tnote{**} & 2.26\tnote{**} & 1.40\tnote{**} & -0.33\tnote{*} & 0.07 & 3.38 & 10.80\tnote{**}\\
        & (0.45) & (0.35) & (0.11) &  &  &  & (0.41) & (0.44) & (0.14) &  &  & \\
        \addlinespace
        4 & 2.25\tnote{**} & 1.44\tnote{**} & -0.36\tnote{**} & 0.18 & 2.09 & 29.38\tnote{**} & 2.29\tnote{**} & 1.23 & -0.27 & 0.06 & 3.41 & 8.52\tnote{**}\\
        & (0.58) & (0.33) & (0.12) &  &  &  & (0.50) & (0.68) & (0.22) &  &  & \\
        \addlinespace
        5 & 2.28\tnote{**} & 1.37\tnote{**} & -0.34\tnote{**} & 0.19 & 1.92 & 31.36\tnote{**} & 2.49\tnote{**} & 1.05\tnote{**} & -0.25\tnote{*} & 0.04 & 3.44 & 5.78\tnote{**}\\
        & (0.56) & (0.33) & (0.12) &  &  &  & (0.52) & (0.38) & (0.12) &  &  & \\
        \addlinespace
        6 & 2.34\tnote{**} & 1.24\tnote{**} & -0.30\tnote{**} & 0.19 & 1.79 & 29.83\tnote{**} & 2.71\tnote{**} & 0.57\tnote{*} & -0.12 & 0.01 & 3.50 & 1.80\\
        & (0.58) & (0.30) & (0.11) &  &  &  & (0.53) & (0.27) & (0.10) &  &  & \\
        \addlinespace
        7 & 2.40\tnote{**} & 1.13\tnote{**} & -0.27\tnote{*} & 0.18 & 1.69 & 27.62\tnote{**} & 2.83\tnote{**} & 0.40 & -0.09 & 0.00 & 3.52 & 0.88\\
        & (0.63) & (0.28) & (0.11) &  &  &  & (0.57) & (0.36) & (0.11) &  &  & \\
        \addlinespace
        8 & 2.48\tnote{**} & 1.03\tnote{**} & -0.25\tnote{*} & 0.16 & 1.61 & 25.02\tnote{**} & 3.07\tnote{**} & 0.27 & -0.11 & 0.00 & 3.52 & 0.44\\
        & (0.65) & (0.26) & (0.10) &  &  &  & (0.62) & (0.72) & (0.21) &  &  & \\
        \addlinespace
        12 & 2.77\tnote{**} & 0.61 & -0.17 & 0.08 & 1.40 & 11.03\tnote{**} & 3.37\tnote{**} & -0.26 & 0.02 & 0.01 & 2.33 & 1.76\\
        & (0.78) & (0.48) & (0.15) &  &  &  & (1.15) & (1.07) & (0.29) &  &  & \\
        \addlinespace
        16 & 2.96\tnote{**} & 0.31 & -0.09 & 0.02 & 1.25 & 3.46\tnote{*} & 3.57\tnote{**} & -0.66 & 0.13 & 0.04 & 2.24 & 5.99\tnote{**}\\
        & (1.09) & (0.36) & (0.16) &  &  &  & (0.78) & (0.41) & (0.15) &  &  & \\
        \addlinespace
        20 & 3.08\tnote{**} & 0.17 & -0.07 & 0.01 & 1.13 & 1.89 & 3.55\tnote{**} & -0.41 & 0.02 & 0.03 & 2.20 & 5.25\tnote{**}\\
        & (0.97) & (0.35) & (0.15) &  &  &  & (0.79) & (0.43) & (0.15) &  &  & \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}
        \note{A general note.}  % changed
        \item[a] A specific note.
        \item[b] Another specific note.
        \item[c] The last note.
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
%        \end{adjustbox}
%    \end{table}
\end{landscape}

Here the normal page orientation continues.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I want to keep the font size consistent with my other tables, so I'm going with the other answer. I already knew about `siunitx`, but removed it from my MWE to make it minimal. Thanks for the `\note` suggestion though.

Comment: @Alexander91, as you wish. Wit other answer your table is bigger than text area. Is this coexistent with your other tables in document?